# How to explain the numerical discrepancy between FactoMineR::PCA() and the svd() in their output of the U matrix?

Tags: r, pca, matrix, matrix-decomposition

I am comparing the output of two functions in R to do Principal Component Analysis (PCA), the `FactoMineR::PCA()` and the `base::svd()` using the R built-in data set `mtcars`, given that the former function is a wrapper of the latter, so they should converge on basic results of the $U$ if everything is fine, $\Sigma$ and $V$, since $X = U\cdot \Sigma \cdot V^{T}$

```
# PCA using FactoMineR::PCA()
library(FactoMineR)
res.pca <- FactoMineR::PCA(mtcars[, c(1:11)], ncp = 9, quali.sup = c(8, 9), graph = F) # variable 8 and 9 are supplementary not active in the construction of the PCs

# PCA using base::svd()
A <- as.matrix(mtcars[,c(1:7,10,11)], row = 9, byrow = T)
S <- scale(A)
svd.pca <- svd(S)

# comparison in terms of V (they match up after correction for signs)
round(res.pca$svd$V, 2) == round(svd.pca$v, 2) # Mixed TRUE/FALSE
svd.pca$v[, c(5, 7)] <- svd.pca$v[, c(5, 7)] * -1 # correct for signs in columns 5 and 7
round(res.pca$svd$V, 2) == round(svd.pca$v, 2) # TRUE

# comparison in terms of Sigma (they match up after correction for the divisor N-1
round(res.pca$svd$vs, 3) == round(svd.pca$d / (sqrt(nrow(S) - 1)), 3) # TRUE

# comparison in terms of U (they don't match up after correction for signs)
svd.pca$u[, c(5, 7)] <- svd.pca$u[, c(5, 7)] * -1 # correct for signs
svd.pca$vs <- svd.pca$d / (sqrt(nrow(S) - 1)) # to add $sdev to sdv() output and make it match up with FactoMineR $svd$vs
svd.pca$vr <- svd.pca$vs ^ 2 # to add Sigma (variance) to the sdv() output
round(res.pca$svd$U, 2) == round(svd.pca$u %*% diag(svd.pca$vr), 2) # Except for the first column everything else is FALSE, why? 

R> head(res.pca$svd$U[, 1:5])
        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
[1,] -0.2838  0.826 -0.292 -0.249 -1.785
[2,] -0.2722  0.688  0.159 -0.169 -1.559
[3,] -0.9825 -0.230 -0.301 -0.214  0.181
[4,] -0.0920 -1.392 -0.471 -0.608  0.579
[5,]  0.6780 -0.584 -1.478  0.291  0.529
[6,]  0.0212 -1.723  0.160 -1.720  0.299

R> svd.pca$u %*% diag(svd.pca$vr)[, 1:5]
         [,1]    [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
 [1,] -0.2837  0.3041 -0.02606 -0.01165 -0.05780
 [2,] -0.2722  0.2532  0.01413 -0.00792 -0.05048
 [3,] -0.9823 -0.0846 -0.02680 -0.01004  0.00586
 [4,] -0.0920 -0.5123 -0.04202 -0.02848  0.01875
 [5,]  0.6779 -0.2148 -0.13174  0.01363  0.01712
 [6,]  0.0212 -0.6341  0.01426 -0.08059  0.00967
```

As you can see the first column matches up, but other columns don't. So what would be the $U$ matrix in `FactoMineR` representing differently from that of the `svd`? How to make them match up using R?

Apart from the signs, it seems that the $V$ matrix is the same for the two function outpus, but what makes the $U$ different then between them?

**Note**

the scaling is also different between the two functions and this line below will do the correction:

```
A <- as.matrix(mtcars[,c(1:7,10,11)], row = 9, byrow = T)
S.corr <- scale(A) / (sqrt((nrow(A) - 1)/ nrow(A))) # correct for scaling

# to get the scaled data from FactoMineR
df_restored <- res.pca$svd$U %*% diag(res.pca$svd$vs) %*% t(res.pca$svd$V)
```

**Side note**
source code for `FactoMineR::PCA()` can be accessed and viewed by:

```
FactoMineR:::PCA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `FactoMineR:::PCA()` and `base::svd()` is the *scaling* and *negative signs* for some columns inn the dataset.

The below code is a proof of the above:

```
# PCA using FactoMineR::PCA()
library(FactoMineR)
res.pca <- FactoMineR::PCA(mtcars[, c(1:11)], ncp = 9, quali.sup = c(8, 9), graph = F) # variable 8 and 9 are supplementary not active in the construction of the PCs

# PCA using base::svd()
A <- as.matrix(mtcars[,c(1:7,10,11)], row = 9, byrow = T)
S <- scale(A)
svd.pca <- svd(S)
svd.pca$u[, c(5, 7)] <- svd.pca$u[, c(5, 7)] * -1 # correct for negative signs

round(head(res.pca$svd$U), 3) == round(head(svd.pca$u * sqrt(nrow(mtcars))), 3) # correct for scaling my multiplication with sqrt(n)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[6,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```